# Trying to create a function for generating an image of circle with some thickness. Stucked at thickness algorithm

Tags: python, tkinter, geometry

So far l have created a function to generate a circle:

```
def add_circle(diameter, image: PhotoImage, outline="black", thickness=1, fill='', to=(0, 0)):
    img = image
    img.config(width=max(diameter+to[0], int(img.cget("width"))), height=max(diameter+to[1], int(img.cget("height"))))
    center = (diameter/2, diameter/2)  # of the aiming perfect circle, so can be fractional

    # that is a "position" of pixels left up corner
    start_point = (0, diameter//2)  # Start at the right most part of the pixel circle
    img.put(outline, (to[0], start_point[1] + to[1]))
    img.put(outline, (diameter - 1 + to[0], start_point[1] + to[1]))
    while start_point[0] != diameter//2:  # we will move up until reach the top. So a quarter will be drawn

        # we will move either up(North), right(East) or diagonally(North East)
        # we check distance to the aiming circle center from the next possible pixel center positions (so + 0.5)
        # than subtract from the aiming circle radius
        # in other words distances to the aiming circle circumference.
        disE = abs(dist(center, (start_point[0]+1 + 0.5, start_point[1] + 0.5))-(diameter/2-0.5))
        disN = abs(dist(center, (start_point[0] + 0.5, start_point[1]-1 + 0.5))-(diameter/2-0.5))
        disNE = abs(dist(center, (start_point[0] + 1+0.5, start_point[1]-1 + 0.5))-(diameter/2-0.5))

        if disE < disN:
            if disE < disNE:  # so go to right is the nearest to circle. Usually happens at the top of circle
                start_point = (start_point[0]+1, start_point[1])
            else:  # disNE smallest
                start_point = (start_point[0]+1, start_point[1]-1)  # usually to the last half of the circle quarter
        else:
            if disN < disNE:  # up is the best. Usually happens at the beginning, when the vertical line drawn
                start_point = (start_point[0], start_point[1]-1)
            else:   # disNE smallest
                start_point = (start_point[0]+1, start_point[1]-1)  # usually after the vertical part is drawn

        # put right pixel and mirror it horizontally and vertically to form a full circle later
        img.put(outline, (start_point[0] + to[0], start_point[1] + to[1]))
        img.put(outline, (diameter-1-start_point[0] + to[0], start_point[1] + to[1]))
        img.put(outline, (start_point[0] + to[0], diameter-1-start_point[1] + to[1]))
        img.put(outline, (diameter-1-start_point[0] + to[0], diameter-1-start_point[1] + to[1]))
```

it works fine (may be not the most efficient code, so if someone has a better one, I would glad to see it as well). But then I can't find a way to do thickness (new layers should be generated towards the center only). In order to do that I created the other circle inside:
[image]

Then my basic algorithms then were like start between them, fill horizontally (also tried diagonally) up until meet the other circle (using get function to check pixels). And in some cases they worked, but all failed at the thickness of 2. The problem is that I just can't check, if my "pointer" inside, as circles are touching each other. For horizontal algorithm it just started filling inside the second circle. For diagonal method it just escaped the circles and start filling surrounds. I know that l can just make special case for that thickness, but i don't think that it is a good to do. A good algorithm should work nice at least for basic cases, mine are failed in the most possible one.

NOTES:
1.1 I also tried to create many circles inside that one, but this method failed, as some circles can't fit the nearest exactly:
[image]
1.2 also there are a problem of overlapping of two circles, that sometimes some parts doesn't have thickness of two, it could be seen on the picture. That leads to the difficulties to any algorithms I have tried so far
2. I can't use PILLOW or any other external libraries, don't ask me why. Only tkinter library has been used so far. Other build-in libraries may be used.
3. I know, that there are a way to create a circle by using create_oval or something like that, but l want to create an image to then put it on the label. There are some problems, that l can't use any standart canvas objects ( can't use canvas.create . . .), again don't ask why, just can't.

If someone can help, I will be really grateful.

P.S. Sorry for my english

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Show code and other textual information as properly formatted text in the question, not as comment, image or external link.

Comment: Thanks. I Didn't know that I should not post code as an image

Comment: First calculate how many pixels represent the thickness, let's call it `T`. Draw your exterior circumference (with R=Ro). Then draw radious-decreasing circumferences (R=Ro-1*i), till you get the inner one (R= Ro-T). I advise to use fraction of pixels (`R= Ro - 0.75*i` or alike) to avoid creating some 'holes' inside.